# Pandas VLOOKUP with an ID and a date range?

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe, vlookup

I am working on a project where I am pulling blood pressure readings from a third party device API for our patients using python, and inserting it into a sql server database.

The data that is pulled basically gives the device ID, the date of reading, and the measurements. No patient identifier.

The team that uses this data wants me to put this data into our sql database and additionally attach a patient ID to the reading so they themselves can pull the data and know which patient the reading corresponds to.

They have an excel spreadsheet they manually fill out that has a patient ID and their device ID. When a patient is done with this health program, they return the device back to their provider and then that device will be loaned to another patient starting the program. So one device may be used by multiple patients. Or sometimes a patient's device malfunctions and they get a new one, so one patient may get multiple devices.

The spreadsheet has a first/last reading date column but it seems it's not really filled out much.

Here is a barebones example of the readings dataframe:

```
reading_id device_id date_recorded systolic diastolic
123          42107     2022-10-31    194     104
126          42107     2022-11-01    195     103
122          42102     2022-11-03    180     90
107          36781     2022-11-04    110     70
111          36781     2022-11-05    140     85
321          42107     2022-11-06    180     95
432          42107     2022-11-07    130     60
234          50192     2022-11-08    120     75
101          61093     2022-11-11    140     90
333          42107     2022-11-15    130     60
561          12908     2022-11-18    120     90
```

And example of devices spreadsheet that I imported as a dataframe.

```
patient_id  patient_num   device_id  pat_name  first_reading   last_reading
32149           1            42107     bob        2022-10-31    2022-11-01     
41105           2            42102     jess       
21850           3            42107     james                    2022-11-07
32109           4            36781     patrick                  2022-11-05
32109           4            50192     patrick
10824           5            61093     john       2022-11-11    2022-11-11
10233           6            42107     ashley
```

patient_num is just which # patient in program they are. patient_id is their id in our EHR that we would use to look them up. As far as I can tell, if last_reading is filled then that means the patient is done with that device. And if there are nothing in first_reading or last_reading, that patient is still using that device.

So as we can see, device 42107 was first used by bob, but he quit the program on 2022-11-01. james then started using device 42107 until he too quit the program on 2022-11-07. finally, it seems ashley is using that device still to this day.

patrick was using device 36781 until it malfunctioned 2022-11-05. then he got a new device 50192 and has been using it since.

finally, I noticed that there are device_ids in the readings that are not in the devices spreadsheet. i'm not sure how to handle those.

this is the output I want:

```
reading_id device_id date_recorded systolic diastolic patient_id
123          42107     2022-10-31    194     104      32149
126          42107     2022-11-01    195     103      32149
122          42102     2022-11-03    180     90       41105
107          36781     2022-11-04    110     70       32109
111          36781     2022-11-05    140     85       32109
321          42107     2022-11-06    180     95       21850
432          42107     2022-11-07    130     60       21850
234          50192     2022-11-08    120     75       32109
101          61093     2022-11-11    140     90       10824
333          42107     2022-11-15    130     60       10233
561          12908     2022-11-18    120     90       no id(?)
```

Is there enough data in the devices spreadsheet to achieve this? Or is it not possible with the missing dates in first/last date, plus the missing device_id to patient_id in the sheet? I wanted to ask that team to put in a "start date" and "end date" for each patient's loan duration. Though I would have to take into account patients with no "end date" yet if they are still using the device.

I've tried making a function filtering the devices dataframe based on the device ID and date recorded and using df.apply but I think I kept getting errors due to missing data. Also I just suck, but I am still learning.

Thanks for any guidance!

Comment: What does date_recorded represent and how does it relate to first_reading or last_reading? This will be the key. Without having some information to link the device id to WHEN it was being used, you will have no way of knowing which data pertains to which patient.

Comment: date_recorded is when the patient used the device to take their blood pressure, and the reading was automatically transmitted to the portal. and so i think when a patient quits the program, the team at least writes down the last recorded device reading in their sheet

Comment: In that case, we 'should' be able to assume that date recorded is the same date as last_reading. Is this a fair assumption? Obviously this is all dependent on vigilant record keeping by  the relevant people

Comment: no sorry if i didn't explain well enough. this is a long term program. so a patient may receive their device on 11/1/22 and use it until 1/31/23 for example. they would have a reading with a "reading_id" and "date_recorded" for each time they used the device in that time frame. when they quit the program on 1/31/23, their "last reading" would be whenever the last time they used the device was, which the team is just manually looking up via the portal

Comment: but yes, it is rough relying on the record keeping of that team >_<

Comment: Ok so is it fair to assume that all date_recorded data will fall between or on first_reading and last_reading

Comment: Also, if there is no entry for first_reading or last_reading, is it fair to assume NO reading has yet been made?

Comment: no someone on the team told me there's been a reading made for everyone. i assumed if there is no entry for first_reading or last_reading, then the device is currently in use by whoever it is tied to in the spreadsheet. for example 42102 is currently in possession of ashley even tho it was previously used by bob and james

Comment: Sorry jagabee, but I have to agree with cottontail. I actually looked at using the merge fuctions as he suggested but you end up having to make a lot of assumptions about dates. To use these  functions, there must exist data at all rows. Any blanks in last_reading can be adjusted by inserting today's date. if first_read is missing, you can look for the last date it was confirmed to be used and insert that date. But there are some devices with empty first_readings that have never been used before. You can insert an arbitrary date in the past but it starts to get very messy.

Comment: It can be done but room for errors and inaccuracies is high. I would suggest cleaning up the data first and insisting a stringent approach to record keeping. Then you might have a hope

Comment: yea i guess it is a lot of inference(?). like i can only tell ashley got her device sometime between 11/7/22 and 11/15/22 (the first reading coming from that device after james stopped using it on 11/7)